# Отладить запрос SQLPHP

Tags: mysql

Как сделать, что бы при сравнение таблиц ФИО выводилось один раз?

```
SELECT id12, FIO12, Adres12, PhonNumber12, numberOwner12 
FROM $horse, $horseowners 
WHERE ($horseowners.id12 != $horse.numberOwner12) 
and (FIO12 != 'Игнатьев А.П.') and (FIO12 != 'Кротов Г.Т.')")"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первую очередь в ужасе забыть про переменные таблицы и нумерованные имена полей. Сделать ОДНУ таблицу horse и ОДНУ horseowners, с нормальными полями. Цыферку 12 добавить отдельным полем. После этого учиться делать джойны

Comment: А почему у вас условие `($horseowners.id12 != $horse.numberOwner12)` вы специально пытаетесь для каждого владельца показать все дома ему не принадлежащие ?

Comment: @Mike `horse` - это вроде как лошадь, а не дом...